# Power BI - question about local and cloud data source

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi

I am creating a report in Power BI, where some data is imported from a cloud storage system. There is also a local data source (an excel sheet) being used.

My question is, if I publish this report on Power BI service and share it with someone, will they be able to see visuals using local data source as well?

There is also possibility of using Sharepoint. I can create a team in Sharepoint with the local excel file and use that as a source in Power BI. Am I correct in assuming this way people in my sharepoint team will be able to see all data in the report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your scenario with a spreadsheet from a desktop and a cloud data source:

If you prepare the report using import mode in PowerBI desktop and publish it to PowerBI online, then that report data will be visible to all users with access to the report in the provisioned workspace. The caveat is that data will not be able to be refreshed from the Excel file once the report is deployed online. When you create the report on your desktop, you have access to the cloud data and the spreadsheet, then a copy of that data is published to the PowerBI service. When PowerBI service is set to refresh, then it can't connect to your desktop and causes the issue.

To solve this you either need a [personal or standard gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/). This provides the technology for PowerBI to connect to your on-premise (standard gateway) or on-desktop (personal mode) data. Once the gateway is in place, PowerBI can pull data in to the cloud from an on-premise network or a personal desktop to refresh reports.

The other alternative is, as you mention, putting the excel in SharePoint online. This effectively makes the spreadsheet a "cloud data source" and can be refreshed from PowerBI service without the need for a gateway.